# How do I change Webrick server root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

Where is the “scripts/server” file that bootstraps WEBrick and tells where WEBrick should serve files from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout your_rails_app/config/boot.rb

You can configure your app via your_rails_app/config/environment.rb

Comment: Can you update your answer for Rails 3? `config/environment.rb` is nearly empty in rails 3.

Comment: What do you mean? boot.rb still exists in Rails 3. You configure the application in config/application.rb, config/environments/test.rb, development.rb, production.rb and by the files in the initializers folder.